# IF there is the value of I6 in range C170:C999, then set D6 to value of B at index whereever I6 matches C170:C999

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I tried for 3 hours now but can't find a solution to my problem.
I have to set D6 to the value of the cell G on line where I6 and C170:C999 match.
For example I6 matches C200, then D6 should be set to the value of G200?

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(I6,$C170:$G999,5,FALSE)
```